# Malloc and realloc for union of structs linked to array of structs

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, realloc

What's the best way to dinamically allocate memory to an array of structs with union included? I should `malloc` and then `realloc` to `record_user` or to `data_user`? Below I explain more of it, this is the sample code:

## core.h

```
#define MAX_USER sizeof(record_user) / sizeof(record_user[0])
#define MAX_ARTIST sizeof(record_artist) / sizeof(record_artist[0])
/* all my other defines here */

typedef enum {
    admin = 1,
    basic = 0
} type;

typedef struct {
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
} tm;

typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} date;

typedef struct {
    short id;
    char name[MAX_USER_NAME];
    char surname[MAX_USER_SURNAME];
    char email[MAX_USER_EMAIL];
    char password[MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH];
    date birthday;
    date subscription_date;
    tm subscription_time;
    type role;
} user;

typedef struct {
    short id;
    char name[MAX_ARTIST_NAME];
    char genre[MAX_GENRE][MAX_GENRE_NAME];
    char producer[MAX_PRODUCER_NAME];
    char nationality[MAX_NATIONALITY_NAME];
    int starting_year;
} artist;

/* and other structs */

typedef struct {
    enum { USER, ARTIST } type;
    union {
        user *u_user;
        artist *u_artist;
    };
    int size;
} data;
```

## data.h

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

#include "core.h"

extern user record_user[];
extern artist record_artist[];

extern data data_user;
extern data data_artist;
/* etc */

#endif
```

## data.c

```
#include "data.h"

// SOME PRESET DATA
user record_user[] = {
{ 1, "Name 1", "Surname 1", "name1.surname1@email.com", ",+o[oS", { 29, 9, 1996 }, { 7, 3, 2011 }, { 18, 25, 58 }, 0 },
/** The list goes on **/
}

artist record_artist[] = {
{ 1, "Coldplay", { "Pop", "Britpop", "Alternative Rock" }, "Parlophone", "United Kingdom", 1997 },
/** The list goes on **/
}

data data_user = { .type = USER,.u_user = record_user,.size = MAX_USER };
data data_artist = { .type = ARTIST,.u_artist = record_artist,.size = MAX_ARTIST };
```

As you can see, there is a union struct for `artist` and `user`. I decided to create a union struct *in order to pass multiple array of structs to a generic function*. In the full code, I have more unions, but that's not the point to list them all. I just really need to understand what's I'm going to further explain below.

`record_user` like `record_artist` has some preset data that I link to `data_user` and `data_artist` respectively in `data.c`. Now this data needs to be increased during the runtime. I mean if `record_user` has 100 preset data rows (same thing for `record_artist`) in it, I'd like to add more rows or even remove them. For that I know there's `malloc` and `realloc`. I tried to play with it, making some tests and I don't know what's the best way of doing that.

I tried to declare in my `main.c` file the following:

```
int main() {    
    data_user.u_user = (user *)malloc(size * sizeof(user));
    /***/
}
```

but I also tried with this

```
int main() {
    record_user = (user *)malloc(size * sizeof(user));
    /***/
}
```

but as I already imagined I lose all the preset data delcared in `data.c` file.

#### MY GOAL

What I'd like to achieve is to `malloc` **a temp size** for my data (for starting **100**) and then **to link the array of structs (or the union struct), *with the starting temp size*, to my preset data** in order for using them. Naturally, during runtime, I will add more rows, and for that I'll use `realloc` (or even remove them).
This is the sample code of my add function:

```
data *add_data(data *record_data) {
    date record_date;
    tm record_time;

    switch (record_data->type) {
    case USER:
    {
        /* SOMEWHERE HERE I should use realloc to my record_data */
        int ID = record_data->size;
        record_data->u_user[ID].id = ID;
        printf("\n\n\tNEW USER");
        printf("\n\tEnter name: ");
        strcpy(record_data->u_user[ID].name, inputString(MIN_USER_NAME, MAX_USER_NAME));
        printf("\tEnter surname: ");
        strcpy(record_data->u_user[ID].surname, inputString(MIN_USER_SURNAME, MAX_USER_SURNAME));
        printf("\tEnter email: ");
        strcpy(record_data->u_user[ID].email, inputString(MIN_USER_EMAIL, MAX_USER_EMAIL));
        printf("\tEnter password: ");
        strcpy(record_data->u_user[ID].password, inputString(MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH, MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH));
        /* etc for birthday, subscription date */

        record_data->size += 1;

        printf("\n\tUser added!");
        return record_data;
    }
    case ARTIST:
        /* asking for input data */

        return record_data;
    }
}
```

this is how I call the function instead in the `main.c` file

```
int main() {
    /***/
    data_user = *add_data(&data_user);
    /***/
}
```

I don't know how to move here, if I should work with the *struct* `record_user` or the *union struct* `data_user`. If it's the same or not... if I work with the original struct (allocating memory), is the union capable of **reading the new memory size or not**? Or is it best to work with the union struct leaving the original struct untouched?

I hope someone clear my mind!

Comment: You cannot realloc static arrays. If you are going to resize the array, the simplest way is to copy the "preset" portion into the dynamic array during init.

Comment: @Groo how do i copy the preset portion into the dynamic array during runtime? thx for the reply btw

Comment: Inside init, you would have (after doing the correct malloc'ing) something like `memcpy(rec_data->u_user, preset_users, sizeof preset_users);`.

Comment: I'm trying to use the union struct since a pointer on user is already declared in that union struct without creating a new pointer to `record_user`... but still it's not working... what am i doing wrong? Is it also correct my way of thinking?


```data_user.u_user = (user *)malloc(size * sizeof(user));```
```memcpy(data_user.u_user, record_user, size);```

Comment: *"but still it's not working"* - what is not working?